# Creating fat models using CRUD methods in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

According to the cakephp book tutorial, actions like database update are made in controller by checking if $id is set in ulr path, if so save is performed. During this action, cakephp need $this->id, wchich is readed from databade using $this->Model->find();

During this process, $this->request->data is heavely used in controller. It's worth to mention, that Model have got no acceess to $this->request->data.

My question is: Have you got your own strategies to create thin controller and fat model during CRUD actions ?

I have got one big users controller to perform CRUD actions, but models needed to this actions are thin.

In my opinion this actions like below are copied across controller, and i'm lookink for way to write more code in model.

Here is and example of controller method copied many times in controller ( basicly, only model name is changed in all actions like this  )

```
public function strona_edytuj($id = null)
{
$this->loadModel('Page');
//$this->render('strona/strona_edytuj');
if (!$id) {
    $this->recursve = 0;
    $data = $this->Page->find('all');
    $this->set('data', $data);
    $this->render('strona/strona_pokaz_wszystkie');
    return false;
}
$post = $this->Page->findById($id);
if (!$post) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Nie ma takiej strony !'));
}
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
    $this->Page->id = $id;
    if ($this->Page->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Strona została zaktualizowana.'));
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'strona_edytuj'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Wystąpił błąd. Spróbuj ponownie.'));
}
if (!$this->request->data) {
    $this->request->data = $post;
}
}
```

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reduce code by more functions in the model, for example if you need to call your model details just put the function in the model then the flames on the controller.
the only driver I deal with the data obtained by the model.

```
    public function strona_edytuj($id = null)
    {

    $post = $this->Page->name_of_your_function($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Nie ma takiej strony !'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->Page->id = $id;
        if ($this->Page->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Strona została zaktualizowana.'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'strona_edytuj'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Wystąpił błąd. Spróbuj ponownie.'));
    }
    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $post;
    }

}
```

in your model of page

```
public function name_of_your_function($id)
{
   return $this->findById($id);     
}
```

you reduce so much code when making FindByid find or joins

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm already doing so, but i know that i'm reducing controller code by 2 or 3 lines....But thanks.